# Install without installing boot loader

Tags: 10.10, installation, grub2, bootloader

I'm trying to install ubuntu 10.10 without installing any linux boot loader (grub, lilo etc). I remember prior 10.10, there's an option for disabling install boot loader. I couldn't find this option when installing 10.10 now.

Please help. Many thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried the Ubuntu Alternate Install CD?

Comment: Are you looking for a dual-boot installation? which OS is already installed? you need, at least, other OS to manage the boot process. Give us more info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the alternative cd for this, I don't think it's included with the standard desktop cd...

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this... You will need a USB stick. When installing 10.10, you must have your USB stick attached to your computer and then, you just choose to install Grub in your USB Stick from the menu "where to install Grub".. :)
After you finish your installation remove your USB stick and there will be no grub installed in your system !

Comment: Oh? I don't find the "where to install grub" menu in 10.10 installation process. I've googled this and find people saying that install using alternative installer rather than liveCD will prompt this option. I haven't tried yet, but tends to try using alternative installer later.

Comment: I do not recommend alternative installation cd because it is for advanced users. 
The menu for choosing where to install grub is there before your eyes :P 
You just have to choose "Specify partitions" to manually create partitions. Then you will get to "allocate drive space" screen where, in the bottom section it says: "Boot loader : Device for boot loader installation" There you can choose the USB stick that I mentioned above. check this screenshot :http://www.comptalks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Ubuntu-10-10-how-to-450x281.png

Answer (score 0):

Option is still there in 10.10, but changed location since partitioning is the very first operation. Search "advanced" or "more" buttons in partition selection screen (sorry, i don't remember exactly)